# Blockhound is erroring on webclient, when making network calls

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

We are using the reactor framework and making an external network call using WebClient. We are using blackhound to ensure that our code is non-blocking. However, blockhound is throwing the exception below which seems unrelated to any of the application code that we wrote. Below is the exception

```
reactor.blockhound.BlockingOperationError: Blocking call! java.lang.Object#wait
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.net.InetAddress.checkLookupTable(InetAddress.java:1394)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1311)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1277)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1193)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1077)
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:156)
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:153)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils.addressByName(SocketUtils.java:153)
    at io.netty.resolver.DefaultNameResolver.doResolve(DefaultNameResolver.java:41)
    at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:61)
    at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:53)
    at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:55)
    at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:31)
    at io.netty.resolver.AbstractAddressResolver.resolve(AbstractAddressResolver.java:106)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect0(Bootstrap.java:206)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.access$000(Bootstrap.java:46)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:180)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:166)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:577)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:551)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:490)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:615)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:604)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:104)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.trySuccess(DefaultChannelPromise.java:84)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.safeSetSuccess(AbstractChannel.java:984)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register0(AbstractChannel.java:504)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.access$200(AbstractChannel.java:417)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$1.run(AbstractChannel.java:474)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
    at io.netty.channel.kqueue.KQueueEventLoop.run(KQueueEventLoop.java:293)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: There must be some blocking call, man. That's the whole purpose of BlockHound. Unless you show your code, (at least give a github link or something) how is anyone supposed to figure out the problem?

Comment: Hi Pramod, Were you able to find the reason for this? I am also seeing this exception while using spring cloud gateway but not sure where is this coming from

Answer (score -1):

It often happens that the blockhound agent complains about internal blocking code even though it is not ours.

Try this, in your log, you have classes with their methods that are blocking, generally JDK IO operations are blocking and add contention to the main thread.

And `BlockHound` is designed to detect them.

[image]

If with this code even the blockhound agent continues showing error, you must continue adding the classes and methods so that it allows its execution.

```
BlockHound
    .builder()
    .allowBlockingCallsInside("java.lang.Object", "wait")
    .allowBlockingCallsInside("AnotherClass", "anotherMethod")
    .install();
```

`More info:`

- https://github.com/reactor/BlockHound/blob/master/docs/customization.md#dis-allowing-blocking-calls-inside-methods
- `java.lang.Object` in the source of the agent https://github.com/reactor/BlockHound/blob/master/agent/src/main/java/reactor/blockhound/BlockHound.java#L143

If the external service you invoke is aware of the blocking call, you can wrap it with the `Scheduler boundedElastic` to avoid contention in the main-thread or parrallel Scheduler.

Comment: just telling someone to allow a blocking call on a generic function as wait without finding the actual root cause of the problem is bad advice. We have no idea if the code provided is actually blocking, and if a blocking call would get introduced further down the line he would not be able to discover it since your code whitelists all of them.

Comment: I have updated my answer, don't think I wasn't aware of it, anyway such blocking services are not all the time easy to handle, if you have an interesting contribution, I read you.